# Find one child CSS class in one parent CSS class, Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, parent, children

I have multiple elements having CSS class "parent". These elements each have 3 elements with the following CSS classes:

"child1", "child2", "child3".

How can I find in all "parent" elements only the "child3" children with `soup.find_all`?

```
only_child3_classes = soup.find_all(class_="xxxx")
for item in only_child3_classes:
      print(item.text)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the  `class` tag, especially what is in capitals. I removed that tag.

Comment: Which version of Beatiful Soup are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Beautiful Soup version 4.7 or higher, you can use [CSS selectors](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#css-selectors). So in your case:

```
only_child3_classes = soup.select('.parent>.child3')
```